# Rails 4. Two model in view. Unknown number of object in second model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I have 2 models, for example model_1 and model_2.
Model_1 has_many model_2.

For model_1 I have "new" and "create" actions and one view for create objects of both models.

In view I used "form_for" for object model_1 and "fields_for" for object model_2. With one object of model_2 everything is working properly.

But my problem is that I dont know how many objects of model_2 user wants to create. Maybe one or maybe 5. I want that the user could create objects with one view and not creating first model_1 object and then create model_2 objects.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have some stupid idea. If in view I create new fields for model_2 with javascript. How can I transfer all that data to controller in post request? Or it's unrealistic?

Comment: You can pass an array in your post data. In your controller you can iterate over the array creating or updating models as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is perfectly plausible, and has been done before with these resources:

- [Nested Model Form Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
- [Ajax Form Additions](http://pikender.in/2013/04/20/child-forms-using-fields_for-through-ajax-rails-way/)
- [Cocoon Gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

The bottom line way to do this is you need to append the new elements to your form using Javascript. This can then work with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to submit the data as one element

We've done this before - the secret is to use `child_index: Time.now.to_i`, here's the code:

---

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/model1_controller.rb
Class Model1Controller < ApplicationController
    def new
        @model1 = Model1.new
        @model1.build_model2
        respond_to do |format|
           format.html
           format.js { render "add_field" }
        end
    end
end
```

**View**

```
#app/views/model1/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @model1 do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :attribute %>
   <%= render partial: "fields_for", locals: { child_index: Time.now.to_i } %>
   <%= link_to "Add Field", model1_new_path, remote: true, id: "add_field" %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/views/model1/add_field.html.erb
<%= form_for @model1 do |f| %>
   <%= render partial: "fields_for", locals: { child_index: Time.now.to_i } %>
<% end %>
```

**Javascript**

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("#add_field").on("ajax:success", function(data) {
    $("new_form").append(data); // VERY simplistic (can be improved upon request)
});
```

This will allow you to add as many fields as you wish. It's a simple version of what we have, but should help you. Of course, if you need any help / clarification, I can amend!

Comment: I will check your's example later today. Thanks. I think it will help me

Comment: Might need some tweaking, but should help you considerably!